# jQuery automatic fade in/fade out gallery - jQuery not finding images

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a automatic fadeIn/fadeOut gallery on page load. What I also would like to do is make each image a link to a page , `image1` take you to one page `image2` to another and so on. the problem I have is jQuery not finding the images in the subfolder and creating the code for making each image a link. Also as there will be a few of these galleries on the page, can I add a delay to each gallery, so the first gallery loads a few seconds before the next?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="ad1pic">
        <h3 id="imageCaption"></h3>
        <img src="gallery/slides/Daisy.jpg" alt="" id="picture">
    </div>
</body
```

JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript 
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var imageName=["Daisy.jpg","Diamond.jpg","Heart.jpg","Unique.jpg"];
    var imageTitle=["Daisy","Diamond","Heart","Unique"]
    var counter = 0;

    var clickaway =
        function go(){
            $("#picture").fadeOut(3000, function(){
                $("#picture").attr("src", imageName[counter]);
                $("#imageCaption").text(imageTitle[counter]);
                counter++;
                if (counter > 2) {counter = 0;}
                $("#picture").fadeIn(900).delay(7000);
                go();
            });
        }
    clickaway();
    //$("#picture").click(clickaway);
});//end of document ready
```

Comment: Krzysztof Hasiński, you cracked it ! you're a star thank you so much , been pulling my hair out all day ! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array values do not have directory entries, thus the children are loading from the wrong directory.  Either change the array entry to include full paths, or include a base directory attribute for the image that you read with the HTML5 data attribute.  I've included a working example of the later - attempting to leave your original script as intact as possible.

It's bad practice to constantly re-lookup a selector, so I did make one small optimization and store the $('#picture') selector in a variable.  Technically, you should try to limit yourself to one var declaration in the method as well, although it will work as you have it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var imageName=["Daisy.jpg","Diamond.jpg","Heart.jpg","Unique.jpg"];
    var imageTitle=["Daisy","Diamond","Heart","Unique"]
    var counter = 0;
    var $pic = $('#picture');
    function go() {
            $pic.fadeOut(3000, function(){
                $pic.attr("src", $pic.data('basedir') + '/' + imageName[counter]);
                $("#imageCaption").text(imageTitle[counter]);
                counter++;
                if (counter >= imageName.length) {counter = 0;}
                $pic.fadeIn(900).delay(7000);
                go();
            });
        }
    go();
    $pic.click(go);
});//end of document ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ad1pic">
   <h3 id="imageCaption"></h3>
   <img src="gallery/slides/Daisy.jpg" data-basedir="gallery/slides" alt="" id="picture">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, I still have the same problem , there's no image fading in or out , only the 1st image daisy fades in and out then nothing , the caption changes with what is meant to be the image, but no image

Comment: I hadn't loaded it with actual images - putting in some images I see you had a couple small errors with your loop (counter >= array length) as well as an unnecessary function copy to a variable with your go function -- which I removed.   Loads and loops nicely now.   I've edited my original post to reflect those changes.